# Redefining droppable area after current item is removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a grid of logo's. You can either double click the logo to get rid of it or you can drag it to a specified square where I would like it to reveal some details about that logo.

Here is the tool in question:

[Drag or Hide a Logo](http://warcadia.com/site/inxex.html)

I have two questions if you could please assist me:

1. When I drag a logo to the droppable square, how would you reccommend I collect information about that specific logo and reveal the information next to the droppable area?
2. When I double click a logo that has been dropped onto the droppable area, that logo will disappear. After it disappears, how can I redefine that droppable area again and use it for other logos?

*If you see any other information I may have screwed up please let me know the better way of executing. Thank you so much!*

**Here's the jQuery:**

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

$('.imageShowing').dblclick (function() {

  $(this).stop().animate({
    zIndex: '1',
    height: '100',
    width: '140',
  }, 100, function() {

        $(this).rotate({ angle:0,animateTo:90,easing: $.easing.easeInOutExpo })

    $(this).stop().animate({
    zIndex: '1',
    top: '500',
    opacity: '0'
  }, 700, function() {   
  $(this).hide("fast");  
    // Animation complete.
  });
  });
});

}); //end document.ready


$(init);

function init(){
    $('.imageShowing').draggable( { 
    containment: '#wrapper',
    cursor: 'move',
    snap: '#droppable',
    stop: cardDropped,
    start: objectGrabbed,
    revert: true,
    }); 

    $('#droppable').droppable( {
        drop: handleCardDrop,
        hoverClass: 'droppableHover',
        accept: '.imageShowing'
    });

}

function objectGrabbed(event, ui) {
    $(this).stop().animate({
    zIndex: '100',
  },0,function() { 
    $(this).stop().animate({
    opacity: '.5'
  }, 500);

  });
}

function cardDropped() {
    $(this).stop().animate({
    opacity: '1',
    zIndex: '12'
  }, 500);
 }


function handleCardDrop( event, ui ) {
    ui.draggable.draggable( 'disable' );
    $(this).droppable( 'disable' );
    ui.draggable.position( { of: $(this), my: 'left top', at: 'left top' } );
    ui.draggable.draggable( 'option', 'revert', false );
    }

</script>
```

**And the CSS if you need it:**

```
#wrapper { width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto; height: 1000px; position: relative;}
#grid {width: 935px; height: 536px; margin: auto; background: url(images/gridLine.png) repeat-y top; padding:0; position: relative; z-index: 5;} /* height equals 134 X 4. Each horizontal grid is 134 in height and 950px in width */

#logoWrapper {position: absolute; top: 2px; left: 36px }

#logoWrapper ul {text-decoration: none; list-style-type: none; margin:0; padding:0; }
#logoWrapper ul li {list-style-type: none; float: left; position: relative; padding: 0 6px 6px 0; height: 128px; width: 180px; margin: 0;}
#logoWrapper ul li img { margin:0; position: absolute; z-index: 6;}

#bottom { height: 500px; width: 950px; background: #fff; margin: 0 auto; position: relative; z-index: 10;}
#droppableWrapper {border: dashed 5px #666; width: 180px; margin:0 auto; }
#droppable {height: 128px; width: 180px; background: #CCC;};
.droppableHover {background: #333; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question.. For me it would depend on:

a) how much info you will be displaying,

b) where is that info being stored (in the html? data attributes of logo? ajax?)

To me, this feels like more a design question than anything, but once i know where the data is and where it's going, I would just create a function for retrieving it, putting it in a template, and displaying it on the page.  Then hook into your drop callback.

For your second question... It looks like you just need to 'enable' droppable again. Maybe something like `$('#droppable').droppable('enable')` after your dblclick animation is done, but I would look at the jquery docs for specifics on that.